# Jquery Custombox 404 Error

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having an issue with jquery custombox 1.13

```
    <script src="scripts/jquery.custombox.js"></script> 
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#show').on('click', function ( e ) {
        $.fn.custombox( this, { 
            effect: 'fadein',
            });
        e.preventDefault();
    }).trigger('click');
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
 <!-- Start Modal Content -->
<div id="modal" style="display: none;">
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="close" onclick="$.fn.custombox('close');">&times;</button>
    <h4>WARNING: Dear Visitor</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>You have blah blah</p>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End Modal Content -->
```

I have an html element with id=show for the trigger but the modal box keeps giving me Error 404. If I add in `url: '#modal'`, it shows but not properly.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<a href="#modal" id="show">Open modal window</a>
```